# It is possible to stop (return) execution of a inherited class from the super method?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a secure main class that checks if some content is present in memory in the `onCreate()` method (it's a method from Android that you override for generating the screen). If not, tryes to load it. Some classes are extending that class.

All the classes calls the `super.onCreate()` method of the parent class before executing their code. My objective is to break the inherited classes execution if the parent class can't load the necessary data.

If i execute `return` in the `super.onCreate()` method, the inherited onCreate() method continues it's execution, so `return` is not my solution.

Is there a way to achieve this in java?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting sub classes inherit onCreate (and being dependant of it) you can add an abstract method for them to override and call it from onCreate

```
abstract void onChildCreate();

public final void onCreate() {

   //do stuff

   if (isDataLoaded) {
        onChildCreate();
   } 
}
```

Comment: this will not work, because the onCreate of the inherited class is called by te OS, not by the super class

Comment: @NullPointerException Which will mean onCreate in the super class will get called. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can throw any exception in super method, and then catch in sub method, if you need do any action on that case, otherwise do nothing, execution will be stopped.
Small example:

```
class Base {

    public void onCreate() {

        if (true) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}

class Child extends Base {

    public void onCreate() {
        try {
            super.onCreate();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // my code
    }
}
```

Comment: In my example exception was catched and metod execution will be stopped  successfully.